# appending div with partial view content

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending request from my view to the controller which as a result sending partialview page. Result is appended in desired div. Only problem is that partial view content is displayed as source html content (css is not rendered properly).

Since I'm guessing that problem may be inside javascript or partialview view here it is

**partiaView.cshtml**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="product clearfix">
        <div class="l-new">
            <a href="#">
                <!-- -->
            </a>
        </div>
    ...
    </div>
}
```

**jsfile.js**

```
function GetTabData(xdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ('/Home/GetData'),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: xdata }),

        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, item) {               
                $("#mytabDiv").append(item);                
            })
        },
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });
}
```

Thanks

Update:
When I'm using

```
> html
```

instead of `append`

```
$("#mytabDiv").html(item);
```

div content is not populated at all.

Comment: I dont see any div with id as `mytabDiv`

Comment: that div is on the index.cshtml, from that page request is send to js. No need to paste that here.

Comment: did you refer the css file ?

Comment: yep, just tried with $("#mytabDiv").html(item); without luck. Now result div is empty.

Comment: What does /Home/GetData return?

Comment: bunch of html code snippet populated with dynamic data. Inside firebug (console | post) everything looks ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your partial expecting IEnumerable collection you don't need to iterate on js side.
Just send result.

These should work

```
success: function (result) {
           $("#mytabDiv").html(result);                
         },
         error: function () { alert("error"); }
```